# An issues in Creation a new Android Project with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

when I want to import a ADT project in eclipse I found a problem although I follow the the instruction  I go to file > import but the the andriod word dont display it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR9vF.png)
plz help

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Stop using eclipse and move to android studio. You can open eclipse projects on that too.

Comment: Have you configured eclipse to use for  Android Development ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
`The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per our announcement`

Answer (score 0):

From that screen, select General -> Existing project in to workspace and click  Next and select the directory and select the project and click finish.

Answer (score 0):

To configure Eclipse for starting android developnent follow the steps

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

4 Click OK.

5. If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
   7.In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
7. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
8. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
   10.When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

After this Go to File > Import > Android > then follow the steps

If this gives any error follow :

1.File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next

2.Select root directory: /path/to/project

3.Projects → Select All

4.Uncheck Copy projects into workspace and Add project to working sets
Finish